# JQuery .keyup() Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where have I gone wrong? It doesn't work at all. I've compared my code to others but can't seem to spot the problem.

```
 function keyUpListner() {
    $(document).bind("keyreleased", function (e) {
        return false;
    });
    $('canvas').keyup(function (event) {
        switch (event.keyCode || event.which) {
            case 39:
                console.log('Right');
                break;
            case 37:
                console.log('Left');
                break;
            default:
                console.log('Unknown');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Start with an explanation what would you like to do

Comment: Did you run keyUpListener(), since it is a function the binding won't happen if you don't call this function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to set up a listener for a keyup event.
**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").on("keyup", "input", function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode || e.which) {
            case 39:
                alert("RIGHT");
                break;
            case 37:
                alert("LEFT");
                break;
            default:
                alert("UNKNOWN");
        }
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mqd8Q/1/)**